# css make element under the parent

Tags: html, css

i have the html like this :

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b/>
</div>
```

and it shows like

```
 ---------
|   div  |
|        |
|[   b  ]|
 ---------
```

now, i want to make it to

```
 ---------
|   div  |
|        |
|        |
 ---------
[   b    ]
```

b is a list which from db , I cannot know the width so I cannot use something like "bottom: -100px".

```css
.a {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
}

.a:hover>.b {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.b {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  123
  <div class="b">
    <ol>
      <li>123</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `top: 100%;` instead:

```
.a:hover>.b {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`transform: translate(0, 100%);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate).

```css
.a {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
}

.a:hover>.b {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
}

.b {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  123
  <div class="b">
    <ol>
      <li>123</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give `top: 100%;` in `.a:hover > .b` class and remove `bottom:0` property.

```css
.a {
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background : pink;
}
.a:hover > .b{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width:100%;
  background : blue;
}
.b {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  123
  <div class="b">
   <ol>
     <li>123</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  </div>
```